# Give an applet focus on mouseenter?

Tags: jquery, applet

I'm new to JQuery.

I have a page containing an applet, and I'd like to give the applet focus whenever the mouse is over it.

```
$('#appletID').mouseenter( function(){ $('#appletID').focus(); console.log('Debug: entered applet.'); });
```

The code above seems like it *should* work, but it doesn't. When I hover over the applet the browser neither gives it focus nor prints the debug message.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

---

As requested, here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/deployJava.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#appletID').mouseenter( function(){ $('#appletID').focus(); console.log('Debug: entered applet.'); });
});

var attributes = { 
        id: 'appletID', 
        code:'my.applet.class', 
        MAYSCRIPT: true,
        height: '85%', 
        width:'800px'
        } ; 
var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'java/myJNLPFile.jnlp'} ; 
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6'); 
</script>
</head>


<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only input- and anchor-elements can get .focus().
As far as I know you can't even auto-focus on a flash embedded in the page.

If you change your code to work on an input ('< input id="appletID" >') you will see it is working - for supported elements

http://jsfiddle.net/UrSEp/

Answer (score 0):

If you've got this example somehow from Oracle, you should use the deployJava function inside the body section.

Another way to put the focus is calling

```
appletID.requestFocus();
```

Your edited HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/deployJava.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#appletID').mouseenter( function(){ $('#appletID').focus(); console.log('Debug: entered applet.'); });
});

var attributes = { 
        id: 'appletID', 
        code:'my.applet.class', 
        MAYSCRIPT: true,
        height: '85%', 
        width:'800px'
        } ; 
var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'java/myJNLPFile.jnlp'} ; 
</script>
</head>


<body>
<script>
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6'); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Best,
Eder

Comment: Well spotted.  Did you test that?